# How can I divide a range of cells by another range of cells and then sum them up

Tags: numbers

I have a table like this
[image]

how can I do the same thing in Numbers like this

[image]

the screenshot comes from excel, if I do the same thing in Numbers, I will get a complain like this:The range E3:E7 can’t be used as a single value.

Comment: Your formula shows =SUM(B5:J5/B$1:J$1) where are you using E3:E7? And, looking at the contents of E3 to E7 you have a date, a $ and two values... So you won't be using that as a range anyway.

Comment: Can we assume you know how to pin columns and rows as relative and absolute in Excel or Numbers? (The difference between =B$1/B5 and =$B1/B5) and then how to copy formulas to neighboring cells?

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for you reply, the E3:E7 is the thing in my numbers, the photos come from excel, I just want to achieve the same thing in numbers which excel do the way the photo shows

Comment: @bmike yes, I know

Comment: @hongfengzhou You state E3:E7 in the last sentence of your question - which is why I query it....

Comment: @SolarMike just leave the concrete range, I want achieve the same function in the photos from Excel, can you give me some sugestion

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with another area used for intermediate computation. I use another table on a separate Reference sheet.

Example:

```
|---------|---------|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 2       | ...     | SUM(C1:C10) |
|---------|---------|---------|-------------|
| 3       | 4       | ...     |             |
|---------|---------|---------|-------------|
| A1 / A2 | B1 / B2 | ...     |             |
|---------|---------|---------|-------------|
```

(The bottom row would be in the other table.)